# attach mail in django format error: not a pdf or damaged

Tags: django

for my homework, I'm trying to send an attach pdf to e-mail.I have generated pdf that I want to send.
but, when I download the pdf file I have format error: not a pdf or damaged at the opening of the file.

definition of render_to_pdf

**utils.py**

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

**pdf generator function**

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
    context_object_name = 'services'
    template_name = 'pdf.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('configuration/pdf.html')
        f=Reservation.objects.all().filter(Q(valide=True, option__in=Option.objects.all().filter(Q(code_option='GTR', 
        posseder_niveau__in=Posseder_Niveau.objects.all().filter(niveau_id = 1))))).order_by('date_du_jour_reserve')
        c = Plage_Horaire.objects.all()

        context = {
            "c":c,
            'f':f,

        }
        html= template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('configuration/pdf.html', context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            filename = "emploidetemps.pdf" 
            content = "inline; filename=%s " %filename
            download = request.GET.get("download")
            if download:
                content = "attachment; filename=%s" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

**mail function**

```
def mailjoin(request):

    GeneratePDF.as_view()
    email = EmailMessage()
    email.subject = "test"
    email.body='emploi de temps'
    email.from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    email.to = ['xxxxxxxx@gmail.com' ]
    email.attach("emploidetemps.pdf", 'application/pdf')
    email.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

First  - `GeneratePDF.as_view()` returns a callable view, not pdf file do call like -

`file = GeneratePDF.as_view()(request)`

Second your `GeneratePDF` returns **HttpResponse**, you have to save the pdf and then add with full path or just don't use this.

If you do not save then do something like -

```
def mailjoin(request):
    template = get_template('configuration/pdf.html')
        f=Reservation.objects.all().filter(Q(valide=True, option__in=Option.objects.all().filter(Q(code_option='GTR', 
        posseder_niveau__in=Posseder_Niveau.objects.all().filter(niveau_id = 1))))).order_by('date_du_jour_reserve')
        c = Plage_Horaire.objects.all()
        context = {
            "c":c,
            'f':f,
        }
    html= template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('configuration/pdf.html', context)
    email = EmailMessage()
    email.subject = "test"
    email.body='emploi de temps'
    email.from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    email.to = ['xxxxxxxx@gmail.com' ]
    email.attach('emploidetemps.pdf', pdf, 'application/pdf')
    email.send()
```

Comment: I have the same problem Sir

Comment: Please sir  the syntax of attaching the file pdf generated  on mail is it correct?

Comment: ok my mistake I haven't gone through your mailing code, I have updated the anwer.

Comment: Sir, I have a typeError: expected bytes-like object, not HttpResponse